# Join two collection

Tags: c#

I have a collection `persons` that contains `id` and `name`:

```
Dictionary<int, string> persons;
```

> 1 John
>   2 Pitter
>   3 Carl

Then I have a collection with person ids by organization:

```
IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> workers;
```

> 100 - [1,2]
>   101 - []
>   102 - [3]

And finally I have the main entity that contains only OrganizationId:

```
entity.OrganizationId = 100;
```

I need to go through `workers` and get all ids of persons (it will give: `1,2`), to finally get the names of those persons from `persons`. How can I do that?

Comment: it is unclear what are you asking

Comment: what is the problem? it is simple use of linq join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the persons from this particular `OrganisationId`:

```
var personsFromOrganisation = workers[OrganizationId].Select(i => persons[i]);
```

If you want an object that directly associates all `OrganisationId` to corresponding persons (here using a dictionary):

```
var organisationsIds = entities.Select(e => e.OrganisationId).Distinct();
var personsByOrganisation = organisationsIds.ToDictionary(id => id, id => workers[id].Select(pid => persons[pid]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the needed Ids using a Sub-Query and then Join by that:

```
var personsByOrganization =
        from p in persons
        join id in workers.Where(x => x.Key == entity.OrganizationId)
                          .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
        on p.Key equals id
        select p;
```

No-Join Approach:

```
HashSet<int> Ids = new HashSet<int>(workers.Where(x => x.Key == entity.OrganizationId)
                                           .SelectMany(x => x.Value));

Dictionary<int, string> personsByOrganization =
        persons.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.Key))
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I get it without using `join`?

Answer (score 1):

No need for LINQ to get the ID's:

```
IEnumerable<int> orgWorkers = null;
bool containsOrg = workers.TryGetValue(entity.OrganizationId, out orgWorkers);
```

Now it's simple to get the names:

```
List<string> workerNames = new List<string>();
if(containsOrg)
{
    workerNames = orgWorkers
        .Where(id => persons.ContainsKey(id))
        .Select(id => persons[id])
        .ToList();
}
```